# Does pyserial return non-normal datatypes from arduinos?

Tags: python, postgresql, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to add data to a remote Postgresql server, running 9.1. To that end, i have an Arduino with a temperature sensor connected to the COM3 port of a local computer. I connect to it, and read data through the serial port via Pyserial. Then, i use psycopg2 to connect to a remote Postgresql database to store all data. This database works; i can add rows to it as long as i add only numbers i have typed in, IE: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO temperature (date,humidity,temperature) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                    (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),1,1))`

I'm fairly certain this is caused by the serial port from the arduino uno returning something other than ordinary ints/strings/doubles. To that end, i tried to force the input into an int, with no success. I've tried configuring the postgresql database with ints, reals, and smallints. The arduino uno, on its end, prints the data out by running  `Serial.println((float)DHT11.temperature, 2);`
The python code that performs all this:
        import serial
        import psycopg2
        import datetime
        from time import sleep

```
    port ='COM3'
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=0)
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='temperature_data' user='postgres' host='192.168.1.78' password='notafakepassword'");
        cur=conn.cursor()
    except:
        print "I am unable to connect to the database"
 while True:
data = ser.read(9999)
sleep(5)
print 'not blocked'
try:
    pieces = data.split("\t")  #split the data by the tab
    for x in range(0,len(pieces)):
        print pieces[x]
    print 'got to data insertion'
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    a=int(float(pieces[0]))
    b=int(float(pieces[1]))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO temperature (date,humidity,temperature) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),a,b))
    conn.commit() #commit the insert
    print 'data inserted'
except:
    print 'can\'t read any data'
```

Attached is a picture of the most recent postgresql table. Any assistance would be appreciated. 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTUvB.png

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you should do is print the values you are receiving

from arduino you should just be able to do

```
 Serial.println(myFloat);
```

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print , points out that this should just work as intended

it handles it pretty smartly as I recall and sends it as `"2.1342\n"` which is very easy to deal with on the python side

on the off chance you are dealing with packed binary data you can use something like

```
import struct
my_float = struct.unpack("f",my_read_value)
```

## Furthermore, and likely your main problem

I see you are trying to split your data on a "\t" ... but it doesnt appear that you are sending a "\t" in your `Serial.println`

Comment: I've edited my arduino  code:                                       `Serial.print((float)DHT11.humidity, 2);
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print((float)DHT11.temperature, 2);`                                   It's my understanding is now i should be able to split on /t, and it shouldn't insert /n any more.

Comment: so print what you get from `ser.read(9999)` (incidentally you should be sending a terminal character of some sort instead of relying on the timeout ...

Comment: Interestingly, changing the arduino to print instead of println and making python print ser.read(9999) seems to have fixed it. Every now and then, ser.read(9999) returns  2 sets of values, which i suspect is linked to the no endline thing. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

py.serial returns bytes.  You have to make sure any byte array is of the correct length, format and endian-ness before converting it into a float (etc.).  So print out the bytes (perhaps in hex) and check them against the expected types.